# Fiddler - How to reissue N requests sequentially for an hour?

Tags: fiddler

I have 5 requests on my fiddler, one for create-fail, one for create, one for delete, one for clean-up and one for read . I would like to reissue them sequentially for like an hour.

they represent a user performing a typo when creating a resource, getting the error message, correcting the mistake, creating, noticing he created the wrong thing, deleting it and checking if it was really deleted. The clean-up is issued automatically by a automation tool at regular intervals...

So, How can i do it?

PS: I'm not trying to stress/load test my app. I'm trying to capture data around a concurrency problem i've been facing.